# FileHelpers - DelimitedClassBuilder cannot use it

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I'm trying to call a ClassBuilder using FileHelpers library to create a dynamic mapping, the problem is that i could not access to the constructor.
Here's my code

```
using RF.Domain.Interfaces;
using RF.Services.Contracts.Interfaces;
using FileHelpers;

 public class SourceParserService : ISourceParserService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IReadWriteRepository<Society> _societyRepository;

        public SourceParserService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            IReadWriteRepository<Society> societyRepository)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _societyRepository = societyRepository;
        }

        public void ParseDefaultSource()
        {
            var engine = new DelimitedClassBuilder("Customers", ",");
            .....
}
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing:

```
using FileHelpers.Dynamic;
```

Comment: I tried to but no luck. Unfortunately i notice that in the source code of FileHelpers in the section of dynamics i have a if that discard if i'm using .net core, so for .net core we don't have the dynamics option, among others...

Comment: Ah yes. You forgot to say you were using .NET core. This [Github issue comment](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/issues/213#issuecomment-331850739) explains that the `Dynamic` namespace will have to be rewritten for .net core.